# Doctrine2 ignore undefined discriminator classes

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

While using the doctrine2 "class table inheritance" to schedule events of different types.

Hypothetical scheme:

[image: Scheme]

This is all fine but the fact is that - because of our modular in-house system - some classes could be "unregistered" from the discriminator map (in cache?).
When this happens the findAll will throw an exception telling us he cannot find the correct object mapping.

So the option i thought of were:

Rewrite the repository methods (findOne, findBy, etc.) to add a filter to the query.

```
$discrClasses = array();
 foreach($this->_em->getMetadataFactory()->getAllMetadata() as $class) {
        $discrClasses[] = $class->getName();
    }
    $discrQuery = sprintf('f.discr INSTANCE OF (%s)', implode(',', $discrClasses));
```

My question is: is this the right way to handle this or is there a better solution?

Comment: Can you post what your discriminator map looks like?

Comment: Our discriminatorMap is not yet created, we are trying some scenario's to test the possibilities.
/*
 * @ORM\InheritanceType( "JOINED" )
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn( name = "discr", type = "string" )
*/
We've created a "master" entity that hasn't got a @discriminatorMap annotation.
Now the discriminatorMap is created automatically by just extending the child objects.